# can wordpress be used as a front end to python bot?

Tags: python, wordpress

I am new to python and I have written a python crypto currency bot. The bot runs fine.  I would like a web front end to the bot, so I can set the coin I want to trade and the strike price. I was thinking of using Wordpress. Using MySQL to store values the bot would use and also store values sent from the Wordpress page. I see python discussions about using python for web development, so can this all be done with python and I don't need wordpress?

Comment: Have a look at `django` or `flask`.

Comment: If this is just a yes / no question: yes, you can use WordPress to create a UI for a Python backend. But would it be the best approach? Probably not.